# Is there some website that aggregates all the Bitcoin exchange prices so small businesses can find out the current market rate and react accordingly?

Tags: exchange-rate, bitpay

I have a small business in doing repairs and I'm willing to take bitcoin, but i was wondering if there is a site that aggregates all the bitcoin exchange prices so I can get an idea of what price to charge in bitcoins to avoid the day to day volatility. Yes i know i can use bitpay, but I want to be able to just take bitcoin myself and come up with my own merchant rate that i choose and feel comfortable with.

Comment: As a merchant, won't the exchange rate you base your rate on be the exchange that you will be cashing out at?  i.e., would it matter what Mt. Gox's exchange rate is if you will be cashing out at BITSTAMP, for example?

Answer (score 3):

bitcoincharts.com is one of the more popular ones:

http://bitcoincharts.com/

Answer (score 1):

BitPay provides an exchange rate quote:

- https://bitpay.com/bitcoin-exchange-rates

Answer (score 0):

I have written a Python program that looks at bitcoinchart's API and finds the median price. This might be useful if you wanted to automatically adjust prices in an online store.

```
import urllib2
import json

def average(l):
    return sum(l)/float(len(l))
#From fraxel
def median(mylist):
    sorts = sorted(mylist)
    length = len(sorts)
    if not length % 2:
        return (sorts[length / 2] + sorts[length / 2 - 1]) / 2.0
    return sorts[length / 2]

currency = "USD"
url = "http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json"
result = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
prices = json.loads(result)


def by_currency(symbol):
    def f(ticker):
        return ticker['currency'] == symbol
    return f
def by_volume(min_volume):
    def f(ticker):
        return ticker['currency_volume'] > min_volume
    return f
def get_price(ticker):
    try:
        return average((ticker['ask'], ticker['bid']))
    except:
        pass
    print ticker
    raise Exception("Can't find price in ticker")

# Avoid prices in wrong currencies
prices = filter(by_currency(currency), prices)
# Exclude small exchanges
prices = filter(by_volume(100), prices)
prices = map(get_price, prices)


single_price = median(prices)
print single_price
```

Comment: i feel like the online bitcoin prices can be manipulated to an extent. what could be some other ways  besides checking the online exchanges?

Comment: What language is this? Python? Please state it explicitely!

Answer (score 0):

You can place my bitcoin price table on your site:
http://coinrepublic.com/website-tools/

David